# Docker for Win acme.json permissions

Tags: traefik

Traefik v1.3.1
Docker CE for Windows: 17.06.0-ce-win18 (12627)

I have the /acme folder routed to a host volume which contains the file acme.json. With the Traefik 1.3.1 update, I noticed that Traefik gets stuck in an infinite loop complaining that the "permissions 755 for /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json are too open, please use 600". The only solution I've found is to remove acme.json and let Traefik re-negotiate the certs. Unfortunately, if I need to restart the container, I have to remove acme.json again or I'm stuck with the same issue again!

My guess is that the issue lies with the Windows volume mapped to Docker but I was wondering what the recommended workaround would even be for this?

Answer (score 0):

> [Can I change permissions on shared volumes for container-specific deployment requirements?](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/#can-i-change-permissions-on-shared-volumes-for-container-specific-deployment-requirements)
>
> No, at this point, Docker for Windows does not enable you to control (chmod) the Unix-style permissions on shared volumes for deployed containers, but rather sets permissions to a default value of 0755 (read, write, execute permissions for user, read and execute for group) which is not configurable.

Traefik is not compatible with regular Windows due to the POSIX permissions check. It may work in the Windows Subsystem for Linux since that has a Unix-style permission system.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this issue when trying to get traefik running on Docker for Windows... ended up getting it working by adding a few lines to a dockerfile to create the acme.json and set permissions. I then built the image and despite throwing the "Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host security warning" when I checked permissions on the acme.json file it worked!

[[image: chmod600]]

I setup a repo and have it auto building to the dockerhub here for further testing.

https://hub.docker.com/r/guerillamos/traefik/

https://github.com/guerillamos/traefikwin/blob/master/Dockerfile

Once I got that built I switched the image out in my docker-compose file and my DNS challenge to Cloudflare worked like a charm according to the logs.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: You can add `build:` to your service and it will build the image so you don't have to do 2 steps.